# What is $f(t) * g(-t)$ (convolution)?

Tags: convolution

I know that the definition of convolution is the following:

$$ f(t) * g(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\tau) g(t - \tau) \mathrm d \tau $$

Then, which is the correct one between the two:

$$ f(t) * g(-t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\tau) g(\tau + t) \mathrm d \tau \qquad (1) $$

$$ f(t) * g(-t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\tau) g(\tau - t) \mathrm d \tau \qquad (2) $$

I need the explanation, too.

Comment: I know $(f*g)(t)$ but not $f(t)*g(t)$. However, $(f*g)(-t)=(f*g)(t)$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h(t)=g(-t)$. Then the convolution becomes $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau)h(t-\tau)d\tau=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau)g(\tau-t)d\tau$$ This is because $h(t)=g(-t)\implies h(t-\tau)=h(t')=g(-t')=g(\tau-t)$