# Convolution notation & meaning

Tags: notation, convolution

I was having a look at this post: [What is $f(t) * g(-t)$ (convolution)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143535/what-is-ft-g-t-convolution) and had my initial question answered. However, another one shows up.

I know the definition

$$ (f*g)(x) = \int_{-\infty} ^{+\infty} f(\tau)g(x-\tau)d\tau $$

and according to the post I linked above, I know that

$$ f(x)*g(-x) = \int_{-\infty} ^{+\infty} f(\tau)g(\tau-x)d\tau, $$

but is there any shorter way to write this last formula? As before it is written $(f*g)(x)$ instead of $f(x)*g(x)$.

Another question is: what lies behind such an equality? I know that the convolution between two functions is used to measure the similarity between them. But what is the point computing things like $f(x)*g(-x)$ or any other convolution where the variable in brackets isn't the same on both sides?

I apologize if my question has already been asked before. I've looked for it but without success.